# Как перевести строку с кодом клавиш к числу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приходит строка с кодами клавиш, на пример такая строка : 52 , 53 (это цифры 4 и 5 ), как мне автоматически скриптом их расшифровать и привести к числу ?

То есть на входе это коды клавиш 52, 53 а на выходе это это цифры 4 и 5 ? Есть ли библиотеки для таких целей или же можно решить как то по другому ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать средствами самого JavaScript без использования дополнительных библиотек. Для этого есть метод [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode). А вот и пример использования:

```
console.log(String.fromCharCode(52)); // 4
console.log(String.fromCharCode(53)); // 5
```

**UPD:** Кстати `52` и `53` это не только и не столько коды клавиш `4` и `5` сколько ASCII коды символов `4` и `5`.